# Автоматическое перенаправление в указанное время

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать автоматический редирект на странице в указанное время (e.g 17:00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    var date = new Date();

    var TimeStr = date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes();

    if (TimeStr=="17:00")

    window.location.href = "http://newsite.com";

},1000)
```